# Enlarging polygons in a kml file

Tags: qgis, polygon, kml

I have a KML file containing several hundreds of Polygon all around the globe, projected in lat/lon WGS84, decimal degrees. I need to enlarge all the polygons adding 23km at the top and at the bottom of each polygon. Is it possible to do it directly in QGIS without exporting everything in excel and work it out?

Comment: When you say that you need to enlarge the polygon "on the top and bottom", how are you defining that?

Comment: I mean that the polygon needs to be extended just in latitude

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how familiar you are with GIS but within QGIS there is a [buffer tool](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html). The problem you'll face with most of these tools is that they buffer around the whole polygon and not just the northern/southern edges

I hope that helps.
Rowan